# subtract Stock Sales list from Stock Purchases list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of both stock sales & purchases. The **stock purchases** list is as follows:

```
['AAPL', 5, 80], ['AAPL', 10, 85], ['CELH', 12, 85], ['CELH', 13, 75], ['BABA', 13, 50]
```

And the **Sales list**:

```
['CELH', -3, 97], ['AAPL', -8, 100], ['BABA', -8, 60], ['BABA', -3, 40]
```

I would like to get a list of sales with their cost basis (FIFO method) like this:

```
[TICKER, Quantity sold, Sale Price, Purchase Price, Total Profit/Loss]
['CELH', 3, 97 , 85, 36]
['AAPL', 8, 100, 5*80, 3*85, 145]
['BABA', 8, 60, 50, 80]
['BABA', 3, 40, 50, -30]
```

So I'm basically looking for a way to subtract the sales list from the purchase list per stock entry.

I have tried to use zip() to subtract lists, but I can't seem to find out how to subtract lists with string values and specific subtractions like the ones that i'm doing where it has to be the particular stock ticker.

I have also tried to turn the lists into dictionaries, but this gave me a problem with how I enter data into the list. I have a TKinterface that stores user entry into a database (sqlite3) and also into these two lists. If the way to go is dictionaries, then that is fine, I'll just have to find a way to append my data to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but should produce results you indicated:

```
def stockFn(purchase, sale):
    return [sale[0], -sale[1], sale[2], purchase[2], -sale[0]*(sale[2]-purchase[2])]

p = ['BABA', 13, 50]
s = ['BABA', -3, 40]
print(stockFn(p,s))
# ['BABA', 3, 40, 50, -30]
```

Comment: This would work perfectly fine if I'd only have one stock entry in the purchase list & 1 in the sales list. The problem is that the purchase list will exist out of a lot of different stocks, with different data & the sales list also. The problem that I'm dealing with is matching up the sale of a specific stock with the purchase of that specific stock and then substracting them to get the profit with FIFO rules.